# NGINX Location troubles

Tags: nginx

I have django and flask applications running on the same machine through different ports:

Django runs on server:8088
Flask runs on server:666

In NGINX.conf I have the following code:

```
 location / {
            proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8088;

        }

 location ^/server2 {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:666;
        }
```

Django has been running for over a year successfully with this set up, where as flask is a new addition.  Any time I try to access one of the Flask urls I either get a "this url does not exist on this server" error, or on occasion a 500 error (when i've been fiddling).

If I write location information for a specific flask url like this:

```
location /server2/splash {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:666/splash;
            }
```

It works, but I obviously don't want to write individual location information for each and every URL in the flask application.

I've gone through many of the existing Nginx location posts on stackoverflow but I've not been able to get it working.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

this is an example of what I'm trying to achieve, but rather than an individual mapping for each URL, I want a single mapping that covers all URLs:

```
        location /server2{
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:666/splash;
        }

        location /server2/split {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:666/split;
        }

        location /server2/export {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:666/export;
        }

        location /server2/import {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:666/import;
        }
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem? do you had both applications just for localhost? are you using a "nginx server blocks"? I did a tutorial for something similar a month ago! maybe it could help [tutorial](http://s.albertogrespan.com/k6hi)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use the `^` sign?  Just remove it I think it will work:

```
location /server2 {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:666;
    }
```

Comment: I've tried it both ways (amongst others) and they both fail in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you use `location /server2` the `server2` is still being passed to your flask application.

In this case Nginx is doing the following:

```
server.com/server2 => http://127.0.0.1:666/server2
server.com/server2/splash => http://127.0.0.1:666/server2/splash
```

In this case `location` is not doing a rewrite. Always check `/var/log/nginx` (or wherever your logs are located) to check the requests done by the browser and what Nginx looks for after the rules for your site are processed.

What you probably want is to set an `upstream` directive:

```
upstream flask_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:666;
}

server {
    ...

    location /server2 {
        proxy_pass http://flask_server;
    }
}
```